# There is a brown burn mark on my dryer's vent

Tags: dryer

. Is this normal or do we need to unplug the dryer and run?

Comment: A photo or two would be helpful

Comment: A little help on how old it is, last time you performed vent maintenance, and any other information regarding the installation material, number of bends in the ventilation, would be super useful.

Answer (score 2):

No. burn marks are not normally seen on dryer vents. If the scorched mark was caused by excessive heat from the dryer (and not by an unrelated incident) then there is a potential hazard and danger from your appliance. Without more details and photos it will be difficult to offer a specific reason, but these are some suggestions that you can check. After unplugging the dryer cord remove the exhaust duct attached to the rear of the back wall. Using a flashlight peer inside looking for critical build up of lint. Use a vacuum, regardless of what amount of lint is noted, to clean the dryer vent. Continue vacuuming the duct projecting from the back wall of the dryer. Re-install the vent and check for normal operation. If you still have any doubts to the normal and safe operation of your appliance it would be wise to have a professional inspect it and give you his opinion before using it again.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that the clothes,or more specifically a piece of clothing gets stuck between the dryer door and the seal that surrounds it .Friction causes the burn marks.